# Reading the txt is returning the information about the file and not the contents

Tags: python-3.x, io

This is my code
for an ant species indexing program
        import time

```
    import os

    import re

    print ("Welcome to the general purpose")

    print ("library index program in python.")

    print ("This version has been set to find indexed")

    print ("ant species.")

    find_genus_1 = input("please enter Genus")

    find_species_1= input("Please enter species")

    output_base_1 = ('{}{}'.format(find_genus_1, find_species_1))

    output_1 = ('{}{}'.format(output_base_1,'.txt'))

    F = open(output_1,"r")

    print (F)
```

I ran it and it returned below quoted statement.

> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='Lasiusniger.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

instead of the text from the file (shown as below)

- **Scientific classification**
- Kingdom:    Animalia
- Phylum:     Arthropoda
- Class:      Insecta
- Order:      Hymenoptera
- Family:     Formicidae
- Subfamily:  Formicinae
- Genus:      Lasius
- Species:    L. niger

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly tell Python to read the contents of the file object returned by `open()`.  Use `f.read()` or `f.readlines()`.